# Are all other Spell-Like Abilities standard actions?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e

I've seen a lot of questions regarding Spell-Like Abilities but regarding actions and casting time - specifically, do you consider "casting time" as the SP "otherwise noted" part?

A Witch Tree is casting Dominate Person as a: 1 round action or Standard action?

It seems at one point someone added unless otherwise noted in the spell or ability, but is that official?

Answer (score 5):

Spell-Like Abilities default to a standard action unless otherwise noted in either the SP's description *or* the spell's description:

> Usually, a spell-like ability works just like the spell of that name. ...
>
> A spell-like ability has a casting time of 1 standard action unless noted otherwise in the ability or spell description. In all other ways, a spell-like ability functions just like a spell.

-- [source](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#TOC-Spell-Like-Abilities-Sp-)

A [Witch Tree](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/plants/witch-tree-tohc/)'s SP list includes [Dominate Person](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dominate-person), but doesn't explicitly state a casting time. Therefore, it doesn't override the regular casting time of Dominate Person, which is 1 round. So, the Witch Tree would need to spend 1 round to use its Dominate Person SP.